# How do I check my serverless cli version?

Tags: version, ubuntu-16.04, serverless-framework

I am following this [serverless quick start tutorial](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/quick-start/).
Here I see that I must have the `Serverless CLI v1.9.0 or later`.
Ran `$ serverless -v` then I've got `//1.28.0`. In the [serverless gitHub](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/releases) I see current version is `1.28.0 (04.07.2018)`. The same as mine.

How can I check my serverless cli version? Maye another command that could display 1.9.0. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any difference between your *Serverless* version and your *Serverless CLI* version.

You're running `1.28`, while `1.9` *or newer* is required for the tutorial.  Since 28 is higher than 9, [you can be confident](https://www.sitepoint.com/semantic-versioning-why-you-should-using/) that you're in the "or newer" camp.  `1.9` [was released](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/releases/tag/v1.9.0) in March of last year (2017).

In other words, your setup is fine, and there are no other *Serverless* versions to verify.  Hack away!

Answer (score 9):

Running

> serverless -v

give details of all version example below

```
Framework Core: 1.57.0

Plugin: 3.2.3

SDK: 2.2.1

Components Core: 1.1.2

Components CLI: 1.4.0
```

Comment: Note this can take about 5-10 seconds for this to give a result. It isn't broken